# Crop image to square in PHP instead of resizing to same aspect ratio

Tags: php, image, function, joomla, crop

I am using a function in Joomla to resize images when they're uploaded. However, the function resizes images to the same aspect ratio that it started with, using an input of max-width and max-height... i.e. the plugin will resize the image EITHER to the max-height OR to the max-width (depending which is greatest on the uploaded image).

However, I want the ability to crop the image to fill the max-height/max width, and crop off the edges from the centre (whichever is the greatest).

Can anyone offer any assistance please?

Here's the current function I have... thanks!!!

```
<?php
/**
 * easy image resize function
 * @param  $file - file name to resize
 * @param  $string - The image data, as a string
 * @param  $width - new image width
 * @param  $height - new image height
 * @param  $proportional - keep image proportional, default is no
 * @param  $output - name of the new file (include path if needed)
 * @param  $delete_original - if true the original image will be deleted
 * @param  $use_linux_commands - if set to true will use "rm" to delete the image, if false will use PHP unlink
 * @param  $quality - enter 1-100 (100 is best quality) default is 100
 * @return boolean|resource
 */
  function smart_resize_image($file,

                          $string             = null,
                          $width              = 0, 
                          $height             = 0, 
                          $proportional       = false, 
                          $output             = 'file', 
                          $delete_original    = true, 
                          $use_linux_commands = false,
                          $quality = 100
     ) {

if ( $height <= 0 && $width <= 0 ) return false;
if ( $file === null && $string === null ) return false;

# Setting defaults and meta
$info                         = $file !== null ? getimagesize($file) : getimagesizefromstring($string);
$image                        = '';
$final_width                  = 0;
$final_height                 = 0;
list($width_old, $height_old) = $info;
$cropHeight = $cropWidth = 0;

# Calculating proportionality
if ($proportional) {
  if      ($width  == 0)  $factor = $height/$height_old;
  elseif  ($height == 0)  $factor = $width/$width_old;
  else                    $factor = min( $width / $width_old, $height / $height_old );

  $final_width  = round( $width_old * $factor );
  $final_height = round( $height_old * $factor );
}
else {
  $final_width = ( $width <= 0 ) ? $width_old : $width;
  $final_height = ( $height <= 0 ) ? $height_old : $height;
  $widthX = $width_old / $width;
  $heightX = $height_old / $height;

  $x = min($widthX, $heightX);
  $cropWidth = ($width_old - $width * $x) / 2;
  $cropHeight = ($height_old - $height * $x) / 2;
}

# Loading image to memory according to type
switch ( $info[2] ) {
  case IMAGETYPE_JPEG:  $file !== null ? $image = imagecreatefromjpeg($file) : $image = imagecreatefromstring($string);  break;
  case IMAGETYPE_GIF:   $file !== null ? $image = imagecreatefromgif($file)  : $image = imagecreatefromstring($string);  break;
  case IMAGETYPE_PNG:   $file !== null ? $image = imagecreatefrompng($file)  : $image = imagecreatefromstring($string);  break;
  default: return false;
}


# This is the resizing/resampling/transparency-preserving magic
$image_resized = imagecreatetruecolor( $final_width, $final_height );
if ( ($info[2] == IMAGETYPE_GIF) || ($info[2] == IMAGETYPE_PNG) ) {
  $transparency = imagecolortransparent($image);
  $palletsize = imagecolorstotal($image);

  if ($transparency >= 0 && $transparency < $palletsize) {
    $transparent_color  = imagecolorsforindex($image, $transparency);
    $transparency       = imagecolorallocate($image_resized, $transparent_color['red'], $transparent_color['green'], $transparent_color['blue']);
    imagefill($image_resized, 0, 0, $transparency);
    imagecolortransparent($image_resized, $transparency);
  }
  elseif ($info[2] == IMAGETYPE_PNG) {
    imagealphablending($image_resized, false);
    $color = imagecolorallocatealpha($image_resized, 0, 0, 0, 127);
    imagefill($image_resized, 0, 0, $color);
    imagesavealpha($image_resized, true);
  }
}
imagecopyresampled($image_resized, $image, 0, 0, $cropWidth, $cropHeight, $final_width, $final_height, $width_old - 2 * $cropWidth, $height_old - 2 * $cropHeight);


# Taking care of original, if needed
if ( $delete_original ) {
  if ( $use_linux_commands ) exec('rm '.$file);
  else @unlink($file);
}

# Preparing a method of providing result
switch ( strtolower($output) ) {
  case 'browser':
    $mime = image_type_to_mime_type($info[2]);
    header("Content-type: $mime");
    $output = NULL;
  break;
  case 'file':
    $output = $file;
  break;
  case 'return':
    return $image_resized;
  break;
  default:
  break;
}

# Writing image according to type to the output destination and image quality
switch ( $info[2] ) {
  case IMAGETYPE_GIF:   imagegif($image_resized, $output);    break;
  case IMAGETYPE_JPEG:  imagejpeg($image_resized, $output, $quality);   break;
  case IMAGETYPE_PNG:
    $quality = 9 - (int)((0.9*$quality)/10.0);
    imagepng($image_resized, $output, $quality);
    break;
  default: return false;
}

return true;
  }
```

Comment: You need to take the minimum of width and height, scale that to the target dimension, and then additionally just calculate the correct values to use for `src_x`/`src_y` …

Answer (score 0):

have you tried phpthumb? it's an include that you can use to resize images (and create thumbnails of said images). You can also crop and zoom crop to make images the shape you wish.

http://phpthumb.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Hi, yeah I've seen that, but ideally need to stick to what I have here, as it's a small part of a wider plugin... this plugin already does the resizing perfectly and integrates everywhere it's needed... it's just the cropping that I can't get to work... Thanks!